# Changing the Default Cache Path for All HuggingFace Data

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface

The default cache path of huggingface is in  `~/.cache/huggingface`, and in that folder, there are multiple cache files like `models`, and `hub`.

The [huggingface documents](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/cache) indicates that the default `dataset` cache location can be modified by setting the shell environment variable, `HF_DATASETS_CACHE` to a different directory as shown below:

```
$ export HF_DATASETS_CACHE="/path/to/another/directory"
```

However, my objective is to alter the default cache directory for all HuggingFace data and not solely the `dataset`. I am facing difficulties in finding the respective shell environment variable in the HuggingFace documentation to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the variable is `HF_HOME` as [this document](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/package_reference/environment_variables#hfhome) indicates. So probably this terminal code should be the solution:

```
export HF_HOME="/path/.cache/huggingface"
export HF_DATASETS_CACHE="/path/.cache/huggingface/datasets"
export TRANSFORMERS_CACHE="/path/.cache/huggingface/models"
```

p.s. If you want to make your change permanent, you should write these lines in your `.bashrc`(Can do with `.bash_profile` too) file using `nano ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

it is need to set this variables before import transformers and torch
Like this

```
import os
PATH = '/home/user/NEW_MODEL_CACHE/'
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = PATH
os.environ['HF_HOME'] = PATH
os.environ['HF_DATASETS_CACHE'] = PATH
os.environ['TORCH_HOME'] = PATH

from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM
import torch
```